# getting undefined error when adding Value to Array in Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

the below value i got by debug when running this code : `staredAppsArray.getItem(0)`

```
{
"starArr": []
}
```

I want to add value to that starArr.

Below I tried the **code**. But showing undefined error in runtime:

```
 let star: Starred = new Starred();
 this.staredAppsArray[0].starArr.push(3);
```

**Model class:**

```
export class Starred {

    starArr :ObservableArray<number> = new ObservableArray<number>();
}
```

Getting undefined array error when tried above code.I want to add that value 3 into that json structured array.

Comment: Why `this.staredAppsArray[0].starArr.push(3);`. What's `this.staredAppsArray`?

Comment: this.staredAppsArray is parsed array from json.

Comment: Could you create a sample here https://stackblitz.com/ in order to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
// If you haven't already initialized staredAppsArray, you need to do that.
this.staredAppsArray = new Array<Starred>();

// Here, you create star, but it is never added to staredAppsArray.
let star: Starred = new Starred();

// Add it here.
this.staredAppsArray.push(star);

this.staredAppsArray[0].starArr.push(3);
```